# Is it possible to style a child based on a parent's dynamic property?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a QWidget designed with QtCreator that contains 3 subwidgets (2 Qlabels and a QComboBox). Is it possible to add a dynamic property to the parent widget that would style the subwidgets using stylesheets (without adding the dynamic property to the children)

this is what the widget looks like when selected is false
[image: this is what the widget looks like when selected is false]

all backgrounds should be red, not just the main widget.

```
void widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)
{
    bool sel = !select; // the widget class contains the select member
    setProperty("selected",QVariant(sel));
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);
}
```

CSS

```
QWidget[selected=false]
{
background: red;
}

QWidget[selected=true] 
{
background: blue
}
```

This approach will only set the background for the custom widget but not for the members. I want to set the background for all members. Is it possible without setting the dynamic property for all children ?

Comment: well.. you could make the background color for the children transparent, or perhaps you could use something like QWidget[selected=true] div
{
background: blue
} to set a color for all the children of type div

Comment: selected is a property you created ?

Comment: Yes, it's a dynamic property.